# Exception handling as per java coding standards

Tags: java

i have one query regarding java standards in case of exception handling.

code snippet:

```
public String methodXXX(){
//This method may throw IllegalArgumentexception and arrayoutofboundaryException.
}
```

In this case, Which is good coding standard and please let me know why
case1:

```
public String methodXXX() throw IllegalArgumentexception,ArrayoutofBoundaryException.{
//This method may throw IllegalArgumentexception and arrayoutofboundaryException.
}
```

case2:

```
public String methodXXX()throws Exception{
//This method may throw IllegalArgumentexception and arrayoutofboundaryException.
}
```

Why i am mentioning case2 here is: we might not expect there can be other exception can occur, while run time.
As Exception is parent class for all exceptions, case 2 is preferable ???
If yes, in which cases case1 is feasible?
Can u please explain me performance point of you also?

Comment: Always be explicit when throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

It's always much better to declare the specific exceptions a method throws. This not only makes it clearer what possible problems might occur, but it makes it easier to handle them separately if necessary.

There aren't really any performance ramifications: creating the stack trace for an exception is such an expensive operation that it dwarfs all other considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Both exceptions are `RuntimeException` subclasses, you don't have to explicitly declare them in the `throws` part of the method declaration.

In Java there are two kinds of exceptions: [checked and unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explaination). As explained in the link, each one is used in different circumstances. All exceptions which are subclasses of `RuntimeException` are unchecked exceptions, and in general you're not supposed to declare that a method throws them.

Comment: It's not really that you're not *supposed* to, it's just that you don't *have* to. It's still useful information to declare them if you explicitly throw them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `RuntimeException`s like `IllegalArgumentException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` reflect *programmer error*, as opposed to an exception that the final program should know how to handle at runtime.

Generally, it's not worth explicitly declaring `RuntimeException`s, since the proper way to respond to such an exception is usually to just throw up, so the programmer who's running the program knows that there's a bug that needs fixing, and can get the stack trace.  It's not usually a good idea to write a `try/catch` that catches a `RuntimeException`, so there's no point.

With regards to other kinds of `Exception`s, you should declare the specific exceptions that might be thrown, so that users of your method can catch each of them individually and write different responses to each of the specific exception types.  Just declaring that you're throwing `Exception` forces users of your method to write exception handlers that can't do anything intelligent, since they don't know anything about the specific exception that was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not throw exception instead put it in the java doc comment. This way user of your api is aware of what kind of exception can happend and is not forced to capture those exceptions.

```
/**
 * @throws IllegalArgumentexception
 * @throws ArrayoutofBoundaryException
 */
public String methodXXX() {
  //This method may throw IllegalArgumentexception and arrayoutofboundaryException.
}
```

I prefer Runtime Exception over checked exception, as most cases forcing to catch exception wont help much. So putting all the exceptions in the java doc make it clear also as well as wont force to catch it. This way the code is cleaner and chances of propagation of exception to top layers is there by default. Else I have seen many developers just catch the checked exception and dont do any thing, leaving top layers un-aware of any exception happening the lower layers.

General thumb of rule is 'If user can recover from exception throw checked exception else document run time exception' And even then I prefer the latter as check exception are generally not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The question to ask yourself: will this method ever be implemented by someone else.  For example, will someone create a subclass and override this method.  Or is this an interface that someone else will implemented.

Those are the crucial questions to ask, and the problem is that you may not know at this time whether someone in the future will subclass and override the  method.  How can you know this.

If you are confident that nobody else will ever implement or override the method, then specify the exact exceptions help to document what the method is doing.  Remember that if change the logic or if methods you call in the logic ever change, then you may need to update the signature of this method.

If it is possible that someone might implement or override the method you should not specify the signature.  If the new implementation is in a new package, that method might need to throw an exception that is applicable to that package.  This is particularly imporant if the new implementation is calling into a library that throws completely different exceptions.  Because the new implementation is an override, the signature constrains in an unacceptable way.  In this case you should declare the generic Exception (or no declaration at all) so that other implementations or overrides are not unnecessarily constrained.

Some additional details can be found here: [Method Exception Signature Guidelines](https://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2013/04/04/method-exception-signature/)